# Getting the maximum of a random ranged selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

This is my array

```
[0.12, 0.13, 0.3, 0.5, 0.75];
```

From this array I calculate the sum cumulative array:

```
[ 0.12, 0.25, 0.55, 1.05, 1.8 ]
```

I generate rand value between the min and max value from the array:

```
var randNumber = (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

in the following case the `min=0.12` and the `max=1.18`

I need to get the interval of the cumulative array in which the rand number falls in. 
For example the rand number could be `1.5948337644897403` then the number falls between 1.05 and 1.8 then I will pick the `1.05`

the issue is that the last element of the array is never picked out. How get the last element of the array?

Comment: `the number falls between 1.05 and 1.8 then I will pick the 1.05` Then when will you pick `1.8`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I think that's the problem. The logic is wrong. I don't understand why you are using this method to get a random number form the array, @Mazzy?

Comment: @thefourtheye this is what I'm trying to resolve

Comment: @Izzey what I'm trying to make is a random weighted selection

Comment: @Mazzy What are considered as the weights? The cumulative sums?

Comment: the weights are in the first array above. the second array is the cumulative sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting a random value between `min` and `max`, and also that you are getting the value lower than the random value. The item that is excluded is actually the first item, but because you get the wrong item all the weights will be wrong, and you will never get the last item.

You should get a random value between zero and `max`, otherwise you will exclude the first item in the array:

```
var randNumber = Math.random() * max;
```

You should then get the item with a value that is higher than the random number:

```
var index = arr.length - 1;
while (index > 0 && arr[index - 1] >= randNumber) index--;
```

Here is a test that shows that the weights are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/kgbL4rsc/